# git error when pushing/pulling: unable to open object pack directory (Function not implemented.)

Tags: git, openafs

I'm using Git Bash on Windows, and using an AFS cell as a remote server. When I try to push or pull, I get the following error message:

```
error: unable to open object pack directory: ./objects/pack: Function not implemented
```

I get that every time, BUT as far as I can tell the remote is updated correctly otherwise (except for the pack directory). I haven't seen this error before, and it only happens for my repos that use the AFS cell as the remote. I've checked permissions everywhere I can think to check, and I should have full read/write permission locally and on the AFS cell.

One other wrinkle: I also work on an OS X machine, and when performing the same operations with the same repos, I do not see this error.

Answer (score 2):

Googling for some other openafs/git related issues brought me to this thread:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.openafs.general/31839

which suggests to use 1.7 versions of OpenAFS for git on windows. I am not sure though whether this also solves your issues.

Best,

Volkmar

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it appears I am in fact using the 1.7 series of OpenAFS.